# materializecss carousel center align unknown number of cards

Tags: php, laravel, materialize

I have a laravel 8 project with materializecss carousel with cards. The carousel is showing 5 items by default. If I have 5 items or more in the DB, then everything is fine. However with less than 5 items, the items are stacking on the left. I need them to be centered all the time doesnt matter the count of them. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col s12 l12 center">
         <div class="carousel center">         
            @foreach($properties as $property) 
            <div class="carousel-item col m4 s8 l3">           
               <div class="card sticky-action borders-top borders-bottom" style="height: 400px;">
                  <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light" style="height: 50%;">
                  @if($property->cover() != NULL)
                     <img class="activator" src="{{ url($property->cover()) }}" alt="office" style="height: 100%;" />
                  @endif
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-content activator">
                  <p class="activator">@foreach($property->locations as $location)
                                    {{ $location->name }}
                                    @endforeach </p>
                     <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4"> {{ $property->property_address }}
                     <p class="activator"> {{ $property->starting_price }} kr</p> 
                     </span> 
                  
                     <p class="activator">{{ $property->propertyType->name }} - {{ $property->m2 }} kvm, {{ $property->size }}</p>
                     <p class="activator">{{ $property->plot_size }} kvm tomt</p>
                     
                     <div class="card-action">
                     <span class="activator left viewing">Visas: {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($property->viewing_date)->isoFormat('ddd D/M') }}</span>
                     <span class="activator right viewing_date bostadonline-text mr-1">Mer Info...</span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-reveal">
                     <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"> {{ $property->property_address }} <i class="material-icons right">close</i>
                     <p class="activator"> {{ $property->starting_price }} kr</p> 
                     </span>
                     <p> {{ $property->short_description }} </p>
                     <p class="center"> <a href="{{ url('/fastigheter/' . $property->slug) }}" class="btn bostadonline-blue-bg-btn mt-2">Lägg bud </a></p>
                  </div>
               </div> 
            </div>                    
            @endforeach
         </div>  
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was overcomplicating things. I had set fullWidth on carousel to true and that messed things up. Then I had added some unnecessairy css modifcations that I had to remove. Basically, the solution was to set fullWidth to false on carousel properties. I didn't need to change my code on the question.